# UnknownHostException on parsing XML file in an Android application

Tags: android, parsing, permissions, android-asynctask, host

I wrote an application Android to parse a XML file wich is situated online. I use JDOM and AsyncTask and it works great but only when I'm connected in WIFI.

When I'm connected in 3G, it doesn't work anymore. I've got the message "Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "jeancdc.perso.sfr.fr": No address associated with hostname".

This is the log file : [log](http://jeancdc.perso.sfr.fr/log_testjdonasynctask.txt).

In my Manifest.xml file, I've added the permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Could someone help me please ? Thanks by advance.

Below is my XMLReader class followed by my MainActivity class.

```java
package fr.jcdc.exemple.jdomasynctaskxmlreader;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.JDOMException;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;

import android.util.Log;

public class XMLReader {

    private Personnage[] personnages;

    public XMLReader() {
        super();
    }

    public void loading() {

        Log.i("tag","fonction loading.");

        try {

            SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();

            Document document = (Document) builder.build(new URL("http://jeancdc.perso.sfr.fr/fichierXML.xml"));

            Element rootNode = document.getRootElement();
            List<Element> charactersList = rootNode.getChildren("personnage");

            personnages = new Personnage[charactersList.size()];

            for (int i = 0; i < charactersList.size(); i++) {

               Element node = (Element) charactersList.get(i);

               personnages[i] = new Personnage();
               personnages[i].setPrenom(node.getChildText("prenom"));
               personnages[i].setNom(node.getChildText("nom"));
               personnages[i].setFonction(node.getChildText("fonction"));

               Log.i("tag", node.getChildText("prenom") + " " + node.getChildText("nom"));      
            }

        }
        catch (IOException ioex) {
            Log.d("ioex", ioex.getMessage());
            ioex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (JDOMException jdomex) {
            Log.d("jdomex", jdomex.getMessage());
        }

    }



    public Personnage[] getPersonnages() {
        return personnages;
    }


}


// Rajouter dans le fichier AndroidManifest.xml :
// - android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" pour gérer le changement d'orientation
// et ainsi éviter le crash de l'application
// - la permission ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

package fr.jcdc.exemple.jdomasynctaskxmlreader;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {

            new GetXMLDataTask<Object>().execute();
        }
        else {

            AlertDialogBuilder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialogBuilder(this);
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Pas de connexion");
            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Veuillez vérifier votre connexion à Internet.");
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }

    }





    private class GetXMLDataTask<XMLItem> extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<XMLItem>> {

            private XMLReader xmlReader = new XMLReader();
            private ProgressDialog progressDialog;


            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                progressDialog.setTitle("Téléchargement des données");
                progressDialog.setMessage("Veuillez patienter.");
                progressDialog.show();
            }


            @Override
            protected List<XMLItem> doInBackground(String... arg0) {

                xmlReader.loading();

                return null;
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<XMLItem> result) {

                try {

                    List<HashMap<String, String>> liste = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                    HashMap<String, String> hashMap;

                    for (int i = 0 ; i < xmlReader.getPersonnages().length ; i++) {
                        hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        hashMap.put("nom", xmlReader.getPersonnages()[i].getPrenom() + " " + xmlReader.getPersonnages()[i].getNom());
                        hashMap.put("fonction", xmlReader.getPersonnages()[i].getFonction());
                        liste.add(hashMap);
                    }

                    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplication(), liste,
                            R.layout.liste_personnages, new String[] {"nom", "fonction"},
                            new int[] {R.id.tv_prenom_nom, R.id.tv_fonction});

                    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
                catch(NullPointerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }

            }

        }


        @Override
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            HashMap<String,String> hmPersonnage = (HashMap<String,String>) l.getItemAtPosition(position);

            Toast.makeText(this.getApplication(), hmPersonnage.get("nom"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }
```

Comment: Can you access http://jeancdc.perso.sfr.fr/ in your device's browser when you are on 3g?

Comment: Yes, I can access to it when I'm on 3G.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host" Exception always occur when you don't provide access internet permission but you have added required permission then your host server is not responding within time because of internet speed, due to lac of internet speed this exception might occur.